# How to request separate folder view path based on controller name in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, model-view-controller, routes, sinatra, slim-lang

Here's the contents of my `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`:

require 'sinatra/base'
require 'slim'
require 'colorize'

```
class ApplicationController < Sinatra::Base

  # Global helpers
  helpers ApplicationHelper

  # Set folders for template to
  set :root, File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../'))
  puts root.green
  set :sessions,
      :httponly       => true,
      :secure         => production?,
      :expire_after   => 31557600, # 1 year
      :secret         => ENV['SESSION_SECRET'] || 'keyboardcat',
      :views          => File.expand_path(File.expand_path('../../views/', __FILE__)),
      :layout_engine  => :slim

  enable :method_override

  # No logging in testing
  configure :production, :development do
    enable :logging
  end

  # Global not found??
  not_found do
    title 'Not Found!'
    slim :not_found
  end
end
```

As you can see I'm setting the views directory as:

`File.expand_path(File.expand_path('../../views/', __FILE__))`

which works out to be `/Users/vladdy/Desktop/sinatra/app/views`

In `configure.ru`, I then `map('/') { RootController }`, and in said controller I render a view with `slim :whatever`

Problem is, all the views from all the controllers are all in the same spot! How do I add a folder structure to Sinatra views?

Comment: You seem to have the `views` (and `layout_engine`) configuration options mixed up with the options hash for `set :sessions`. It should be changed to `set :views, ...` (and similarly for `layout_engine`).

Comment: Move your `whatever.slim` to `views/root` and then render it with `slim 'root/whatever'`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to override `#find_template`.

I stick this function in a helper called `view_directory_helper.rb`.

```
helpers do
    def find_template(views, name, engine, &block)
      views.each { |v| super(v, name, engine, &block) }
    end
end
```

and when setting your view directory, pass in an array instead, like so:

```
set :views, ['views/layouts', 'views/pages', 'views/partials']
```

Which would let you have a folder structure like

```
app
    -views
        -layouts
        -pages
        -partials
    -controllers
```

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with same task. I have little experience of programming in Ruby, but for a long time been working with PHP. I think it would be easier to do on it, where you can easily get the child from the parent class. There are some difficulties. As I understand, the language provides callback functions like **self.innereted** for solving of this problem. But it did not help, because I was not able to determine the particular router in a given time. Maybe the environment variables can help with this. But I was able to find a workaround way to solve this problem, by parsing call stack for geting caller class and wrapping output function. I do not think this is the most elegant way to solve the problem. But I was able to realize it.

```
class Base < Sinatra::Application

  configure do
    set :views, 'app/views/'
    set :root, File.expand_path('../../../', __FILE__)
  end

  def display(template, *args)
    erb File.join(current_dir, template.to_s).to_sym, *args
  end

  def current_dir
    caller_class.downcase!.split('::').last
  end

  private

  def caller_class(depth = 1)
    /<class:([\w]*)>/.match(parse_caller(caller(depth + 1)[1]))[1]
  end

  def parse_caller(at)
    Regexp.last_match[3] if /^(.+?):(\d+)(?::in `(.*)')?/ =~ at
  end
end
```

[The last function is taken from here](http://grosser.it/2009/07/01/getting-the-caller-method-in-ruby/). It can be used as well as default erb function:

```
class Posts < Base
  get '/posts' do
    display :index , locals: { variables: {} }
  end
end
```

I hope it will be useful to someone.